# Share (fb,gplus) , URL from browser address bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to Share address bar automatically in facebook+googleplus

**My Html+js code :**

```
<a class="facebook" target="_blank" href="">Facebook</a>
<a class="googleplus" target="_blank" href="">Google+</a>

<script>
document.getElementById("facebook").href = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + window.location.href;
document.getElementById("googleplus").href = "http://plus.google.com/u/0/share?url=" + window.location.href;
</script>
```

**Empty Result**

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phAyH.jpg)

How Can I fix this Empty Result ,

Comment: id or class? don't mix them up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're targeting ids, not classes :

```js
document.getElementById("facebook").href = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + window.location.href;
document.getElementById("googleplus").href = "http://plus.google.com/u/0/share?url=" + window.location.href;
```

```html
<a id="facebook" target="_blank" href="">Facebook</a>
<a id="googleplus" target="_blank" href="">Google+</a>
```